# Font file data URL violates unsafe-inline content security policy

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types, content-security-policy, data-uri

I'm trying to reference a font file saved as a data URL (trimmed below for readability).

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,T1..">
```

My `style-src` content security policy includes the `unsafe-inline` directive. Why am I still getting the following error?

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,T1..' because it 
    violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe- 
    inline' https://localhost:* https://127.0.0.1:*".
```

Comment: Does a data uri count as inline? Probably not. You might have to add `data:` as an allowed origin...

Comment: It's even listed as an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#hosts_values).